# How to pass parameters in ASP.NET MVC for attributed routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting, redirecttoaction

Here is my model:
Company-->Projects

I created my company which has id = 1. Now, I want to add a project to it. Using MVC attribute routing I am able to go this URL fine: http://example.com/companies/1/projects/create

When I fill in the fields for the project and submit it using HTTPPOST I want to send the user to http://example.com/companies/1/projects/edit/9 <-- 9 being the project which just got created from the create method.

If I do this:

```
return RedirectToAction("{companyid}/projects/edit", "companies", new {companyid = id, id= project.ID });
```

it goes to here and blows up: http://example.com/companies/%7Bcompanyid%7D/projects/edit/9?companyid=1

I want it to go to http://example.com/companies/1/projects/edit/9

Can anyone help me figure out the RedirectToAction() for this please?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to RedirectToAction is an action name (so the name of the method that will get called on your CompaniesController), not the route.

You can either substitute your string "{companyid}/projects/edit" for the action name or use the [RedirectToRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470522(v=vs.118).aspx) method and pass in the name of the route as set up in your routing tables.

Comment: Appreciate your reply. I will try this out and confirm it before I mark your answer as accepted.Thanks again for your reply.